# AWS SSH connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am unable to access Linux EC2 instance through SSH or browser-based SSH.
Earlier I was able to access the same instance through both standalone SSH and browser based SSH, but it suddenly stopped working. Firewall is still applied correctly, I have checked with corporate network team.

```
Instance id: i-0f2560d0590aa21ba

Inbound rules: 
HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0

Outbound rules:
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0

VPC is attached to security group : launch-wizard-1
```

Also, subnet, Route table, VPC configuration is correctly configured.

But still I am unable to access the EC2 instance through SSH.

In case you have ever came across same issue, Kindly let me know and help to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: If an instance is Stopped and Started, it can change IP address. Have you checked that you are using the _current_ IP address or DNS name for the instance? If so, please update your question and show output for `-vvv` option on the ssh command (to show debug log).

Comment: Yes, I've stopped and started a new instnace but I'm using correct IPv4 address of the instance which is  urrently assigned.

Comment: Well, make sure you are using the current "IPv4 Public IP" value when connecting. If that is correct, please show us the `-vvv` debug output.

Comment: ```ssh -vvv "keypairname.pem" ec2-user@ec2-x-x-x-x.ap.south-1.compute.amazonaws.com ``` It says: failed to open file .....ssh/config error 2, ssh: could not resolve hostname keypairname.pem : no such host is known

Comment: Sorry for readability, I am not allowed to copy paste due to corporate limitation. One more thing, I am not able to ping to the IPv4 address of the instance. There is no response actually.

Comment: You need to use `-i` before the keypair filename: `ssh -vvv -i keypairname.pem ec2-user@INSTANCE`. Ping is disabled in your Security Group, so it will not work.

Comment: I have been using -i

Comment: Please tell us the error message(s) from the `-vvv` output.

Comment: failed to open file .....ssh/config error 2, ssh: could not resolve hostname keypairname.pem : no such host is known

Comment: That error is saying that you did not use `-i`. Please provide the **full command** you are using.

Comment: ```debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\b.tembhurne/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "ec2-x-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-x-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:00000245A691F670
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-x-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out```

Comment: A timeout normally indicates no network connection (if the connection was refused, it would be rejected immediately). A good test would be to launch another (temporary) EC2 instance in the same subnet and see whether you can connect to it. Then, it's a matter of comparing the differences to identify the cause (which _might_ be the instance, but it is sounding network-related).

Comment: Hmmm...OK. I will check once by creating a new instance. Will update accordingly. Thanks for your co-operation.

Comment: Same issue still there:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PuTTY (64-bit)>ssh -vvv -i "aws-lfd.pem" ec2-user@ec2-13-234-238-12.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\b.tembhurne/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "ec2-13-234-238-12.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-13-234-238-12.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com [13.234.238.12] port 22.`